# Create text label queues for approval in streamlit

Tags: python, html, streamlit

I'm new to `streamlit`. I'm trying to creat a ticketing kind of project where a person can request a ticket and the admin can approve or deny it. I'm facing problems creating text labels something similar to the below image

[image]

I have date below like:

```
[{
"title":"a",
"desc":"Something"
"date":"Some date"
},{
"title":"b",
"desc":"Something else"
"date":"Some else date"
}]
```

Comment: Read the api reference at https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit uses buttons, `st.button`, and you can place them in columns, `st.columns`.

For your layout, I would define 5 columns, with 3 `st.write()` objects, and 2 `st.button()` objects as in:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = st.columns(5)
col1.write(dict['title'])
col2.write(dict['desc'])
col3.write(dict['date'])
if col4.button('Approve'):
    approve()
if col5.button('Disapprove'):
    disapprove()
```

If you want, you can change the size of the columns by giving the st.columns() method a list of 5 parameters, such as [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], which would size your buttons larger than the labels.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's Giving an error.
`AttributeError: __enter__`

Comment: Try my edited answer above!